# Using Outlook 2007 with the rest of the Office 2003 suite

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2003

Is it possible to use Outlook 2007 with the rest of the Office 2003 suite?

Are there incompatibilities which will cause problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can install different versions of different Office products simultaneously.  The installer will ask if you want to replace the old version or install side-by-side.

For example, at work I have both Access 97 and Access 2003 installed to handle both older and newer versions of MDBs.